# SQL Server NT Authority/system logged in (thousands of times) + Hanging up

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am running SQL Server 2012 enterprise 11.0.6598. Seeing in the logs "`Login succeeded for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'. Connection made using Windows authentication. [CLIENT: server IP]`"

This is happening somewhere around 150 times per minute, and simple queries have begun to lock my tables for hours and have to be killed manually (doesn't happen every time, but happens from SSIS jobs more often I believe). Both issues started last night on our production box at close to the same time, but I am not 100% convinced that they are related. Server is having no resource issues, and traffic is no higher than usual. Anyone seen anything like this before?

More info

**Edit 1:** The small group of admins do not recall making any changes or deployments, and the problem started after hours.

**Edit 2:** Found where the server is occasionally failing to authenticate with the domain controller. Not my area of expertise, but I guess I need an expert.

Comment: Well what did you or someone do/deploy last night as that time?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have checked with the small team that has access to make changes or deploy to this server, and they have no explanation. Jobs and queries that have worked for years are now suddenly failing. Also, the problem started three hours after anyone would have been in the building making changes.

Comment: Start a trace/profiler on the server and see if you can capture any additional info.

Comment: Found where it is failing to authenticate with the domain controller intermittently. Not sure how it is causing this, but I believe that I have a road to go down.